# How to autoload venv/bin/activate in vscode on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have django project folder with venv environment.
when opening vscode it has terminal opened in vscode.

Is there a way that I don't have to venv/bin/activate all the time when opening the project folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit (credit to @XJOJIX) from the comment in this answer. This will active the virtual environment without having to close or open terminals. A Python file still needs to be selected to load the Python extension.

Add this parameter in VS Code to "launch.json" or  ".code-workspace"

```json
    "settings": {
        "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true
    }
```

Previous Answer:

To have a VS Code terminal automatically activate a virtual environment when first launching VS Code:

1. Close the terminal before exiting VS Code.
2. Open VS Code. Ensure a Python file is selected to direct VS Code to load the Python extension.
3. Wait for the Python extension to finishing loading (very bottom
   left of VS Code terminal).
4. Open a new terminal after Python extension has loaded. The venv will automatically activate.

The trick is to open the terminal only after the Python extension has loaded.

If the directory of the terminal contains a virtual environment, VS Code will also automatically activate a virtual environment if a new terminal is opened. As before, a Python file must be selected and the Python extension must be fully loaded.

Comment: OMG! it does WORK! but I have to open the .py file to load the Python extension. Is there a work way around for this? or do I just have to get used to it?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that part. A python file has to be selected to let VS Code know to load the Python extension (answer has been edited). I don't believe there is a workaround as the terminal will always immediate load while the Python extension takes some time. Since the terminal loads first, VS Code isn't aware the terminal will be used for Python.

Comment: Thanks Jason. it seems straight forward even theres a work folder settings, vscode won't know if you are going to use python or not. makes a lot of sense. vscode can't determine if it's a project folder or not.

Comment: I've found a workaround.
simply add the following in User or Workfolder settings.
`"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,`

it'll auto load whenever python extension loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac OS, the simplest thing is to make ENV for your python projects.

Follow these simple Command in your Vs Code Terminal and you get your ENV activated :

```
Python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

(The  env in the first line is your env name so you can type any name)

Comment: Easiest way to do that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command palette to trigger the "Python: select interpreter" command. It should allow you to pick your virtual environment.

[image]

The article [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) migth be of interest to you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it only adds   "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python", in the .vscode/settings.json in the work folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use window machine, it might locate at

```
env/Scripts/activate
```

You can run above in your vscode terminal to activate your `venv`